# Singleton and Scope

Tags: spring, scope, javabeans

```
<bean id="userFacade" class="com.test.facade.UserFacadeImpl">
            <property name="userDao" ref="userDao"/>
            <property name="currentUser" ref="user"/>
</bean>
<bean id="user" class="com.test.beans.User" scope="session">
    <aop:scoped-proxy/>
</bean>
```

UserDao and user are passed to it - user being a scope and facade a singleton. So any request to userfacade is going to return a same object but user will be different for each session - the concept session inside a singleton confuses me. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 2):

The "scoped proxy" is a transparent wrapper around your `User` bean. When a method on that proxy is invoked, it will look up the current `HttpSession` using Spring's thread-local mechanism (called the `RequestContextHolder`), and then fetch the `User` object from inside the session's attributes. If none exists in that session, a new one is created and stored in the session. The "real" method on that `User` is then invoked.

The big caveat with scoped proxies is that the proxy's methods can only be invoked if the scope is "active", e.g. if the currently executing thread is a servlet request.

Answer (score 1):

The instance of `User` injected into `UserFacadeImpl` is a proxy which delegates method calls to the actual session-scoped instances of `User`.

**See also:**

- [Proxy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern)

Comment: Oh!! ok so that what <aop:scoped-proxy/> is doing . I was referring to some examples and I saw the UserFacadeImpl is annoted as @Service what does it mean and how it is different from @Resource.

Comment: @Jerry: See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-annotation-config